# C# how to convert a double to string with exponential notation

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert double to string in format of exponential notation.
for example:

```
double l_dNum = 3.333;
        string l_strNum = l_dNum.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(l_strNum);
        //Wanted results: 3.33e+00
```

Thanks!

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#EFormatString

Comment: (I'd also advise you to use more conventional variable names, but that's a different matter...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string l_strNum = l_dNum.ToString("E");
```

If you want up to 2 decimals only

```
string l_strNum = l_dNum.ToString("E2");
```