# how to convert from double to exponential notation in c#

Tags: c#, data-manipulation, exponential

How to convert double number to exponential notation in c#?

My number
I would like number will look like:

> -1.6500000000000000e1

I looks on the article:

[C# how to convert a double to string with exponential notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32421609/c-sharp-how-to-convert-a-double-to-string-with-exponential-notation)

But this didn't fully answer me:

```
number.ToString("e16", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

provide me number looks like:

```
-1.6500000000000000e+001
```

I would like at the end only e1 for non negative, or e-1 for negative

Thanks!

Comment: @LijuThomas No, read my question again please

Comment: Yes, it is a dupe. Just replace E2 with E15 or so.

Comment: @HenkHolterman But the mentioned aritcle didn't solve me the issue..also e^16 didn't solve my issue at the end of the exp.

Comment: Sounds like you'd need a custom format string, like `0.0000000000000000e-0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using *formatting*:

```
  Double value = -1.6500000000000000e1;

  // e15 - exponential form, small "e" for exponent, 16 digits
  String result = value.ToString("e16", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

  Console.Write(result);
```

**Edit**: in case you want "e1" form of exponent, you should specify it like this:

```
  String result = value.ToString("0.0000000000000000e0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I got -1.650000000000000e+001 instead to got at the end only e1 - how can I solve it please?

Comment: @Programmer: then change format a bit (see my edit)